# How to detect when UIWebView starts loading when Webview is inside a Collection View cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uicollectionview, uiwebviewdelegate

I am loading a collection view of cells containing `UIWebView`s.  There's a time gap between when my `UICollectionView`'s activity indicator stops spinning and the `UIWebView` loads.  I am trying to get a reference to when the loading starts (and eventually when it stops) in order to add another activity indicator UI.  I'm not sure how to do it here though since my `UIWebView` is in my `CollectionViewCell` and not my `CollectionView`, in other words I can't use the delegate methods and set myself as my delegate in my `collectionView`s VDL?   My `CollectionViewCell` code:

```
 import UIKit
import WebKit

class SearchCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    @IBOutlet weak var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        print("we're loading")
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `UIWebViewDelegate` in your cell and set you cell as `delegate` then in the method `webViewDidStartLoad` you will be notified

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class SearchCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    @IBOutlet weak var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.webView.delegate = self
        // Initialization code
    }

}

extension SearchCollectionViewCell : UIWebViewDelegate
{
    public func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        debugPrint("Start Loading")
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you!  Setting the delegate in `awakeFromNib` was what I couldn't figure out....and great use of an extension!

Comment: Your welcome, I am glad to help you, happy coding and best regards! @GarySabo