# Web View Exception

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am loading a URL request in web View and sometimes I am getting the following warning in logs. Due to the warning, `webViewDidFinishLoad` never gets called.

> WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: delegate:  attempt to delete item 1 from section 0 which only contains 1 items before the update.

I have added web view in the collection view cell.

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: have you added NSAppTransportSecurity and NSAllowsArbitraryLoads?

Comment: @AtulParmar Yes

Comment: Please post full log, what is the warning after `delegate :`

Comment: @andesta.erfan edited.

Answer (score 1):

Add an exception breakpoint. This will fire when the exception is raised, which will let you see what's happening.

[image: Debug>Breakpoints>Create Exception Breakpoint…]

It is possible to encounter harmless caught exceptions that will fire this breakpoint, but they're very rare, so generally if this breakpoint fires, it's a legitimate problem. Don't confuse these exceptions with Swift `throws`. They're not related.

Comment: It is only giving WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: delegate: But the app does not get crashed.

Comment: Understood, but does the Exception Breakpoint fire? Also, have you implemented the webView(_:didFinishLoadFor:) delegate method? This error suggest that there is a mistake there (not webViewDidFinishLoad)

Comment: Yes, the Exception Breakpoint fire. Also webViewDidFinishLoad it is already added.

Comment: Great; if the exception breakpoint fired, you should be able to see what is generating it in the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You should try following solution to fix you issue:

1. In `Info.plist` file add a dictionary with key '`NSAppTransportSecurity`'
2. Add another element inside dictionary with key '`NSExceptionDomains`'
3. Add element with key '`YourDomainName.com`' of type `NSDictionary`
4. Add element with key '`NSIncludesSubdomains`' of type `Boolean` and value set as `YES`
5. Add element with key '`NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads`' of type `Boolean` and value set as `YES`

It will looks likes as follows:

[image: Info.plist]

I hope this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting the WebView’s delegate in the awakeFromNib call for the CollectionViewCell. [How to detect when UIWebView starts loading when Webview is inside a Collection View cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682779/how-to-detect-when-uiwebview-starts-loading-when-webview-is-inside-a-collection)